# MySQL date converstion

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table in MySQL, where I have a date and time column. Where format of this column is `01 February 2013 12:49:40`. I want to extract the date part and time part as well as month part also. I am using `month(01 February 2013 12:49:40)` this function but it's throwing error. I can't use the `Substring`, as the width of the row is not equal. What should I do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First convert it to a real date (what you have is just text, MySQL doesn't know it's a date)

```
 SELECT STR_TO_DATE(your_column, '%d %M %Y %H:%i:%s')
```

then you can use functions like year(), month(), time(), whatever to get what you want...

```
 SELECT YEAR(STR_TO_DATE(your_column, '%d %M %Y %H:%i:%s')) FROM your_table...
```

Even better would be of course, to change the column to datatype datetime or timestamp. Then you could spare yourself the STR_TO_DATE() function every time.

Do so by adding a column datetime or timestamp to your table

```
ALTER TABLE your_table ADD COLUMN your_column datetime;
```

Then "copy" your column with

```
UPDATE yourTable SET new_column = STR_TO_DATE(old_column, '%d %M %Y %H:%i:%s');
```

Then you can drop your current column.

```
ALTER TABLE DROP COLUMN your_current_column;
```

Or choose another approach, several possibilities...